# show arrow only when tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PBvk9/

I want the arrow for its respective tab to show up only when the tab is active. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered your CSS to account for the `active` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Vgff/

This is the relevant section:

```
ul.tabs li.popular-posts.active .tab-arrow { background:url("http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/9985/tab1active.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;bottom:-5px;height:5px;position:absolute;right:44px;width:11px }
ul.tabs li.lorem-ipsum-1.active .tab-arrow { background:url("http://img255.imageshack.us/img255/4915/tab2active.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;bottom:-5px;height:5px;position:absolute;right:44px;width:11px }
ul.tabs li.lorem-ipsum-2.active .tab-arrow { background:url("http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/4931/tab3active.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;bottom:-5px;height:5px;position:absolute;right:44px;width:11px }
```

Comment: oh wow how simple! here i was trying to figure out how to change the javascript. thank you, i'll accept your answer in about 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your stylesheet

```
.tab-arrow{display:none;}
.active .tab-arrow{display:inline;}
```

Basically, it hides all the arrows except for those with an active parent. Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/bPzFp/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.tabs li .tab-arrow {
    display: none;
}
ul.tabs li.active .tab-arrow {
    display: block;
}
```

## [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/PBvk9/4/)